# Get Text Line By Line From PDF using C#

Tags: c#, pdf

I have a PDF file that I want to split its text line by line,

and save it to a plain text file using C# code. I need to us only free library.

I tried many libraries, the closest I got is with [PdfPig](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PdfPig/):

```
using (PdfDocument document = PdfDocument.Open(@"fileName.pdf")){
   var page = document.GetPages()[0];
   var wordsList = page.GetWords().GroupBy(x => x.BoundingBox.Bottom);
}
```

this gets most of the lines but not all of them, any help in fixing

this current code, another idea I had is to try to retrieve the `\r\n`

from the pdf file and `Split("\r\n")`  on it, this will also work

but the PdfPig library don't output the `\r\n` in their `GetWords()` method

Comment: There is no such thing as "a PDF file". PDF is a wide variety of specifications, versions and special cases. You could encounter PDFs with (correct) text layer, PDFs with a "bogus" text layer (textlayer-content != image text content), Image-Only PDFs, ... Also, PDF is not restricted to organizing its text content in lines. It could appear vertically, crocked, in a spiral, "artistic", name it.

Comment: And: recommendations for libraries is explicitly off-topic on SO.

Comment: @Fildor I change the question foucs

Comment: @Fildor another thing BitMiracle Doctic library has this feature so it can be done in pdf

Comment: They can have features all they want. Sooner or later you'll encounter a PDF that breaks your approach. The easiest way to mitigate is to force the providers of the files to deliver pdfs that meet certain agreed-upon criteria. For example having a valid text-layer that you can use easily. But that's rather non-technical to reduce the problem's complexity. You may or may not be able to make such agreements. If not, all you can do is "best effort".

Comment: @Fildor Ok so I would love to see someone else best effort it may be better than my

Comment: You need to define your input more precisely than "a PDF". A PDF may be image-only, which renders you completely without any text to process. Which means you'd have to do OCR. SO you need to detect that and go path 1. Then you could have a text layer, that's completely unrelated to what the rendered image is showing. That difficult to detect but I guess you could come up with some heuristics if you know enough about the expected text. That leaves you with fail: -> do OCR despite present text layer -> Redirect to path 1 or success: use the text layer. 1/2

Comment: 2/2:  Beware that your observed lack of some lines may be a combination of this: You do have a text layer that contains _most_ of the text but some of it is only in the rendered image (I've seen this with Letter Heads or footers) so to say "in the background". As if you would print a text onto a preprinted letter-sheet.

Comment: @Fildor my pdf contains text and 2 images I don't need the images only the text. and the problem I encountered was that some lines were broken to 2 lines but they are actually one line

Comment: So, they are 2 entries in some sort of array, while they are rendered on the same line? Like that? And semantically, it's one sentence? Is that restricted to a specific language? Or could it be any language or only a few select ones?

Comment: ^^ I mean, if e.g. you kow it should be english and disregarding typos, you could look for sentence-terminating interpunctuation chars ( .;!?... ) and if the entry does not end in one (ignoring whitespace), you could append the next one and so on.

Comment: @Fildor I understand what you suggested but there isn't such terminating signs,
and the problem is that visually it's in the same line like other rows but from some reason, it's been divided into 2 places in the array, other rows exactly like this get it right and is placed in 1 place in the array.

Comment: Do you know if the text layer is generated or added by OCR? I had this happen in OCR, when there is a nearly invisible jump in text alignment, so the software considers, what appears to be one line to the human eye, to be 2 lines. That's not easy to fix if you do not have any meta-data like text position etc. or even influence on the OCR parameters (which I guess you do not have control over if it's OCRed in the first place).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246187/discussion-between-ben-s-and-fildor).

Comment: You group by the bottom of the bounding box. Words with descenders have a different such bottom than words on the same line without descenders. But even if that property contained the bounding box for the whole font at its size and not the word in question, the bottom would change wherever the font or the font size changed on a line. Here the base line would be a better choice than the bounding box bottom. But even the base line may not work if the line contains subscripts or superscripts. Detecting text lines in general is non-trivial.

Comment: @mkl I don't find an option to group by baseline in pdfpig am I missing something ?

Comment: I have to admit I don't really know pdfpig, merely PDFs as such. Thus, the base line is probably what you need, but I don't know whether pdfpig exposes that property.

Comment: I had a quick glance at the pdfpig code; `Word` does not seem to have a baseline attribute but `Letter` does. Thus, you may retrieve the first `Letter` of a `Word` and use its  `StartBaseLine` or `EndBaseLine` point. Beware, though, as said above, for a full-fledged line recognition you'll need some more complex algorithm.

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same problem. My humble solution is like this:

```
using (PdfDocument document = PdfDocument.Open(path))
{
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

     foreach (Page page in document.GetPages())
     {
        var wordsList = page.GetWords().GroupBy(x => x.BoundingBox.Bottom);

        foreach (var word in wordsList)
        {
            foreach (var item in word)
            {
                builder.Append(item.Text + " ");
            }
            builder.Append("\n");
         }
      }
      string text= builder.ToString();
 }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This type of

> text line by line

output is the standard **-layout** format as output by xpdf pdftotext, however that  effectively needs license for commercial use, hence the forked variation cross platform more liberal variant poppler **pdftotext.**

For Windows use the latest https://github.com/oschwartz10612/poppler-windows for others see https://poppler.freedesktop.org/

You can export all pages by default or without breaks (-nopgbrk) or one page at a time to file or console but beware screen/console encoding can mess about with appearance due to current codepage, many encodings are possible to cater for European, Hebrew, Arabic or CJK glyphs.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the page layouts in the [PigPdf Wiki](https://github.com/UglyToad/PdfPig/wiki/Document-Layout-Analysis#advanced-case-2) and developed the following solution from it, which is not perfect, but quite good for my purposes.

```
/// <summary>
/// Returns a sequence of words in the order they appear in the PDF, based on an unsupervised reading order detector.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="page">The page to extract words from.</param>
/// <returns>A sequence of words in reading order.</returns>
private IEnumerable<Word> GetWordsInReadingOrder(Page page)
{
    // Extract all words from the page using the NearestNeighbourWordExtractor
    var words = page.GetWords(NearestNeighbourWordExtractor.Instance).ToList();

    // Use DocstrumBoundingBoxes to group words into blocks based on their proximity to each other
    var blocks = DocstrumBoundingBoxes.Instance.GetBlocks(words);

    // Use an UnsupervisedReadingOrderDetector to determine the reading order of the blocks
    // The parameter 10 is used as a tolerance value for coordinate values
    var unsupervisedReadingOrderDetector = new UnsupervisedReadingOrderDetector(10);
    var orderedBlocks = unsupervisedReadingOrderDetector.Get(blocks);

    // Iterate over the ordered blocks and return all words that intersect with each block's bounding box
    foreach (var block in orderedBlocks)
    {
        var wordsList = words.Where(x => x.BoundingBox.IntersectsWith(block.BoundingBox)).ToList();
        foreach (var word in wordsList.Where(word => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(word.Text)))
        {
            yield return word;
        }
    }
}
```